# Send Plain Text Email from SharePoint Designer 2013 Workflow

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

As the title says, I am looking for a way of sending plain text emails from SPD 2013 Workflow. I have found [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/79586/send-plain-text-email-from-sharepoint-designer-2010-workflow) similar post for 2010, but I am hoping there's a workaround for 2013 which I have not found yet.

I removed html tags by editing the email's body through the properties of the send email action, but the email is still being sent with the following html tags:

- Starts with `<html><head><base href='...' /></head><body>`
- Ends with `</body></html>`
- `<br>` for line breaks

Is there any way to strip out these tags? Or should I go for a solution in Visual Studio?

Answer (score -1):

You can change the workflow to a 2010 workflow that will remove the html scripting out of the email.

Comment: And how do you do that?