# Online - Missing spaces in emails sent from Workflow

Tags: workflow, email, discussion-board, online

I've created a SharePoint 2010 Workflow. This Workflow sends an email with a simple body (no tables, just regular/bold text) when a new post is created in the discussion board on SharePoint Online. Everything is working fine, also the body of the email in the SharePoint Designer editor looks fine.

But when I receive the email on my Outlook 2016 (I faced this issue on Gmail too) some white spaces are missing between words.  For example, in the email Sharepoint joins the words "al portale" together to make "alportale".  I really can't understand why.

Is this a known bug? Is there a way to resolve?

Comment: if you have any column:value embedded in your email - check the columns names to see if any have spaces in them, perhaps this could explain the blank spaces.  Would it be useful to post a picture so we can see the blank spaces?

Comment: Hi @Tally, thanks for your reply. This is an example https://imgur.com/a/qY1d9 (sorry it's in italian) of the received email. The highlighted text is where blank spaces are missing. Except for the bold text that is the title of discussion coming from SharePoint, the other text is just normal text inserted in the editor on SP Designer. For example: "è stato" is like "it has been".

Comment: Oh, I like Italian very much!  OK, so I understand that "alportale" should read "al portale".  I had a look around for other people with the same issue or a similar kind of issue.  This might be worth reading:  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/106c5930-8b09-4868-986a-7c9548b8c7c9/sharepoint-designer-send-email-removes-spaces?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy or else https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/79586/send-plain-text-email-from-sharepoint-designer-2010-workflow